# Angular testing streams in store

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs, observable

I have 2 services `AuthenticationStore` and `NavigationStore` that have `user$` and `links$` streams as properties where `links` depends on `user$`; `user$` can be adjusted by `login()` of `logout()` methods of `AuthenticationStore`.

Services are working as expected, I have problem with unit test them and set up expectations. My test code looks like this:

```
describe('NavigationStore', () => {
  const AuthenticationStoreService = { user$: new BehaviorSubject<User>(null) };
  let NavigationStoreService: NavigationStore;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        NavigationStore,
        {
          provide: AuthenticationStore,
          useValue: AuthenticationStoreService
        }
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();

    NavigationStoreService = TestBed.get(NavigationStore);
  });
  it('should have Logout Admin user', async(() => {
    AuthenticationStoreService.user$.next({
      id: '',
      email: '',
      group: 'A',
    })

    NavigationStoreService.links$.subscribe(
      (links) => {
        expect(links).toEqual([
          {
            title: 'Logout',
            path: '/logout',
            acl: 'A'
          }
        ]);
      }
    );
  }));

  it('should have Login Guest user', async(() => {
    AuthenticationStoreService.user$.next({
      id: '',
      email: '',
      group: '0',
    })

    NavigationStoreService.links$.subscribe(
      (links) => {
        expect(links).toEqual([
          {
            title: 'Login',
            path: '/login',
            acl: '0'
          }
        ]);
      }
    );
  }));
});
```

I have a mix of `Spec ... has no expectations.' or the second test has results for Admin user (like have a value from the previous test).

Code for services:

**NavigationStore**:

```
const links: Navigation[] = [
  { title: 'Login', path: '/login', acl: '0' },
  { title: 'Logout', path: '/logout', acl: 'A' },
];

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class NavigationStore {
  private subject = new BehaviorSubject<Navigation[]>(null);
  links$: Observable<Navigation[]> = this.subject.asObservable();

  constructor(private auth: AuthenticationStore) {
    this.links$ = this.auth.user$.pipe(
      map((user) => links.filter((link) => link.acl.includes(user ? user.group : '0')))
    );
  }
}
```

**AuthenticationStore**:

```
const noUser = {
  id: '',
  email: '',
  group: '0'
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthenticationStore {
  private subject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null);
  user$: Observable<User> = this.subject.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    const userProfile = localStorage.getItem(USER_DATA);
    if (userProfile) {
      this.subject.next(JSON.parse(userProfile));
    } else {
      this.subject.next(noUser);
    }
  }

  login(email: string, password: string): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.post<User>(URL + '/users/login', { email, password })
      .pipe(
        tap(user => {
          localStorage.setItem(USER_DATA, JSON.stringify(user));
          this.subject.next(user);
        }),
        catchError(() => {
          this.logout();
          return throwError('');
        }),
        shareReplay()
      );
  }

  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem(USER_DATA);
    this.subject.next(noUser);
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to move the initialization of `AuthenticationStoreService` inside the first `beforeEach` like this -

```
describe('NavigationStore', () => {
  let AuthenticationStoreService;
  let NavigationStoreService: NavigationStore;

  beforeEach(() => {
    AuthenticationStoreService = { user$: new BehaviorSubject<any>(null) };
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        NavigationStore,
        {
          provide: AuthenticationStore,
          useValue: AuthenticationStoreService
        }
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();

    NavigationStoreService = TestBed.get(NavigationStore);
  });
```

After modifying the code as mentioned, I see that all of your tests are passing. Can you also try and see if it works?